# HDInsight Error

Tags: windows, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, cortana-intelligence

I am following the steps in the link shown below to use Hadoop 2.2 clusters with HDInsight. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-get-started-30/

In the  "Run a Word Count Map Reduce Job"section  I am having difficulty getting the message to take for step 4. In the PowerShell I type in the following commands:

## Submit the job

Select-AzureSubscription $subscriptionName
$wordCountJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition $wordCountJobDefinition

I keep getting an error that states there is a ParameterArgumentValidationError. What command could I use to avoid getting these errors?

I am new to using Azure and could really use some help :)

Answer (score 1):

Those are two separate cmdlets:

The first one is:
Select-AzureSubscription $subscriptionName

If you only have only one subscription with your azure account, you can skip this cmdlet.

The second cmdlet is:

$wordCountJob = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition $wordCountJobDefinition